# Razor page not working with Rewrite

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewriting, razor

I have a .cshtml page in a web forms app. When I go to the .cshtml url directly it displays the page just fine.

I also have a httpmodule that does url rewriting. When I rewrite a url to the .cshtml page I get an IIS error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This type of page is not served.
>
> Description: The type of page you have
>   requested is not served because it has
>   been explicitly forbidden.  The
>   extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect. 
>   Please review the URL below and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /pages/1.cshtml
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Obviously this isn't right because I know the type of page can be served because it works when I go to the url directly.

My rewriter is doing this

HttpApplication.Context.RewritePath("~/pages/1.cshtml", true);

I am running this on IIS7.5 in Windows 7. Does anyone know why this error is coming up? Any suggestions on working around it?

Comment: It looks like this is directly related to the URL being rewritten. I was trying to rewrite a URL with NO extension... ie. http://localhost:1981/rushs-profile but if I rewrite http://localhost:1981/rushs-profile.cshtml to ~/pages/1.cshtml it works.

Comment: futhermore, if I rewrite an extensionless URL to a page with a different type of extensio, like a .htm or .aspx page, it also works. Which makes me think this is just limited to rewriting non-.cshtml URLs to .cshtml pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here...

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/872/webmatrix-beta-release-readme/

You have to add this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to figure this out all day. Just 1 little line makes all the difference.