# ASP.NET RAZOR Urls? Getting 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, webmatrix

I used WebMatrix to play around and do a very simple site for learning. However, when I upload to an actual Windows server (yes, WebMatrix installed) The MVC style url's dont work.

If you go to `http://173.201.29.98:88/` 
You'll see

But if you go to `http://173.201.29.98:88/Default.cshtml`
it works.

Anyone know what's wrong? I'll I've done is upload it, didn't use the "Publish" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, after looking more deeply in Stack Overflow I found the answer.

[Razor page not working with Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279774/razor-page-not-working-with-rewrite)

Pretty Simple.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```